# Struct values not being output (C#)

Tags: c#, list, output

I am trying to create code that will display up to 18 lines of movie information (title, year, genre, quality, director) after finding it in a search, and I'm having a problem with having the code display on the console.

Relevant structs:

```
struct Movie
        {
        public string title;
        public int year;
        public Name director;
        public float quality;
        public string mpaaRating;
        public string genre;
        public List<Name> cast;
        public List<string> quotes;
        public List<string> keywords;
        }
    struct MovieList
        {
        public int length;
        public Movie[] movie;
        }
```

The code in question is below:

```
static void searchMovies(ref MovieList ML, int menuChoice)
{
Movie searchTerm;
float searchRating;
int searchIndex;
int foundIndex;
Movie[] foundMovie = new Movie[NUM_MOVIES];
do
{
int.TryParse(searchMenu(), out menuChoice);
foundIndex = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Enter the movie title to search for");
searchTerm.title = Console.ReadLine();
for (searchIndex = 0; searchIndex < ML.length; searchIndex++)
{
if (ML.movie[searchIndex].title == searchTerm.title)
{
foundMovie[foundIndex].title = ML.movie[searchIndex].title.ToUpper();
foundMovie[foundIndex].year = ML.movie[searchIndex].year;
foundMovie[foundIndex].genre = ML.movie[searchIndex].genre;
foundMovie[foundIndex].mpaaRating = ML.movie[searchIndex].mpaaRating;
foundMovie[foundIndex].director.firstName = ML.movie[searchIndex].director.firstName;
foundMovie[foundIndex].director.lastName = ML.movie[searchIndex].director.lastName;
foundIndex++;
}
}
Console.Clear();
displaySearchResults(foundMovie, foundIndex);
}

static void displaySearchResults(Movie[] foundMovie, int foundIndex)
        {
int displayedLines = 0;
int displayResults;
do
{
for (displayResults = 0; displayResults < foundMovie.Length; displayResults++)
{
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}  {4} {5}",     foundMovie[displayResults].title,                                                               foundMovie[displayResults].year, foundMovie[displayResults].genre, 
 foundMovie[displayResults].mpaaRating, foundMovie[displayResults].director.firstName, foundMovie[displayResults].director.lastName);
displayedLines++;
}
Console.ReadLine();
} while (displayedLines < 18);
}
```

This code is supposed to check the ML.movie[searchIndex].title to searchTerm, and if found, load the ML.movie[searchIndex] values for title, year, genre, rating, and director name (first and last) into the foundMovie struct at the current value of foundIndex. And then, after searching through the entire movie list, go into the display method and print out a line of code including the previously mentioned values (title, year, genre, rating, and director name).

When I run the code and go through the process to search (the ML struct is preloaded with movies from a binary file), when it comes time to display the search results, all I get are a wall of 0s, as seen in the picture.

[image: Example output when running]

Answer (score 0):

You currently call `displaySearchResults` even if there is no match with `foundIndex` 0 - then you proceed to display the first item in your array, which has never been set, hence displays all default values - empty strings and zero (assuming that you use `struct` for your other structures as well).

Two suggestions:

- Use `class` not `struct` - it seems much more appropriate here.
- Don't use a fixed size `Movie` array, use a `List<Movie>` for your
  found movies because you don't know how many movies will match.

Comment: For the first suggestion, I'm actually not able to do so (It's a class assignment, and I'm required to use structs).

For the second, when comparing the List<Movie>, would the code look like:

     `List foundMovie<Movie>;
     if (ML.movie[searchIndex].title == searchTerm.title)
     {
     foundMovie.Add(ML.movie[searchIndex]);
     foundIndex++;
     }
 
And for the display, I changed to: 
 
     if (foundIndex != 0)
     {
     displaySearchResults(foundMovie, foundIndex);
     }
     else
     {
     Console.WriteLine("Results not found");
     }`

Though this simply stops the output...